# Why the compiler always wants this type once (=) is overloaded?

Tags: ocaml

I have a problem that I didn't understand since three days, since I don't understand, I can't solve it.

I have code like this:

```
module SpotLocation = struct
type t = {
    uuid : string option;
    netElement : string;
    coordIntrinsic : float;
}
end


module Segment = struct
    type t ={
        netElement : string;
        coordFrom : SpotLocation.t;
        coordTo : SpotLocation.t;
    }


    let isEqual segA segB = segA.coordFrom = segB.coordFrom && segA.coordTo = segB.coordTo

    let (=) = isEqual (* <<<<<<<<< Here is the problem *)

    let isIn seg loc = (seg.netElement = loc.netElement)

end
```

The problem comes from (=) that I have overloaded.

Once I have it, the compiler insists have the following reaction:

```
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type t
```

I have tried to declare the signature of (=) but it doesn't work.

For example, this gives the same thing:

```
module Segment = struct
type t ={
    netElement : string;
    coordFrom : SpotLocation.t;
    coordTo : SpotLocation.t;
}


let isEqual segA segB = segA.coordFrom = segB.coordFrom && segA.coordTo = segB.coordTo

let ((=) : t -> t -> bool) = isEqual (* <<<<<<<<< Here is the problem *)

let isIn (seg : t) (loc : SpotLocation.t) =
let open SpotLocation in
seg.netElement = loc.netElement

end
```

If I move the (=) after isIn, it works, but once I start to add some more logic it gives the same error. So I don't know what happens.

Could anyone explain this to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no function overloading in OCaml. Once you define a function (or any other type of value for that matter) with a given name, that name will shadow any existing value with the same name for as long as it is in scope.

So once you define your global `=` function, the old `=` is no longer accessible for the rest of the file, except via its fully qualified name `Pervasives.=`.

Comment: So can I define a (=) only for my type?

Comment: @Enzojz You did define a `(=)` only for your type. What you can't do is have your `(=)` and the default `(=)` be in scope at the same time (and have the decision which to call depend on the type). As I said: OCaml does not have function overloading.

Comment: Ok, understand. Thank you!

Comment: @Enzojz If I've got that right, in FP operator overloading is seen critically, because it might be difficult to tell which function will be called at runtime - and it complicates reasoning about the program. And more, OCaml wants to infer the operand type from the operator.